# count(distinct(person_id)) not working with window function in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, analytics

So I found that mysql does not support using aggregate function like count(distinct(person_id)) with window function. For example, the below query will not work.

```
select count(distinct(person_id)) over ([OrderBy clause])
from <table>;
```

**What is the alternative to this problem that works equally fast like window functions?**

**schema:**

```
create table table1(
check_date date,
person_id  varchar(10)
);
```

**My attempted query:**

```
select person_id,count(distinct(person_id))
over (order by check_date range between interval '20' day preceding and current row)
from table1;
```

Need to get count of all distinct persons who checked into the system in a window frame of 20 days.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: mysql  Ver 8.0.12 for macos10.13 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

In MySQL 8+, you can emulate this using two window functions:

```
select sum(seqnum = 1) over (order by ?) as num_distinct
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person_id order by ?) as seqnum
      from <table> t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, can you check the post again? I added more details. I tried your query and it does not work .

Comment: @Zack . . . This answers the original question you asked.  You have asked a different question.  I would suggest that you undo the changes to the question and ask *another* question.

Comment: I just added more details to my question. Supported it with an example. The question remains the same.